# How to convert an IEnumerable<HtmlElement> to a regular HtmlElement

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net

I'm trying to use the `WebBrowser` control in VS 2013 to enter text on a webpage. My app is written in `C#`. The Html for the webpage doesn't use standard ids, but instead it uses something called a `data-gel-id`. I believe this is custom to the company that built the webpage, but I'm not familiar enough with JavaScript to know for sure. This means I can't use the `GetElementsById()`  method to point my app at the specific text box. The Html element is reproduced below:

```
<div class="rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable" data-gel-id="gel_20" style="position: absolute; left: 25.9375%; top: 28.125%; font-size: 12%;">
```

I am trying to use the code snippet below to get the Html element by className. The code is based on a snippet from an MSDN forum [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a22cafb7-f93c-4911-91ce-b305a54811fa/how-to-get-element-by-class-in-c).

```
static IEnumerable<HtmlElement> ElementsByClass(HtmlDocument doc, string className)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement e in doc.All)
        if (e.GetAttribute("className") == className)
        {
            yield return e;
        }
}
```

However, when I try to assign the output of this method to an `HtmlElement` like so:

```
HtmlElement txtbox = ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable");
```

I get an error saying that you can't explicitly convert an IEnumerable to an HtmlElement.

So I have a few questions:

1. Should I try to convert the `IEnumerable` to an Html element? And if
   so, how?
2. Am I using the code snippet correctly? Are my arguments legit?
3. Is this even the best way to point my app at the text box?

Thank you very much for your help and let me know if there's anything else I can post to help with the answer.

Comment: Well yes, your method returns a sequence of elements, and you're trying to assign to a variable with *one* element. What do you want to happen if there are multiple elements with the right attribute?

Comment: ElementsByClass is plural.  So you can either ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable")[0] (add an index to end) of make elements plural declaring it an array: HtmlElement[] txtboxes.

Comment: @jdweng: No, `ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable")[0]` wouldn't work, because `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have an indexer. `ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable").ElementAt(0)` or `ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable").First()` would. Changing `txtboxes` to an array wouldn't help either, without calling `ToArray()` - again, because the method returns `IEnumerable<HtmlElement>`, not `HtmlElement[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the "custom id", you should probably try something like this

```
var gelId = "gel_20"; // This is the id you know
var txtbox = ElementsByClass( doc2, "rcPoint rcPointtext rcPointEditable")
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttribute("data-gel-id") == gelId);
if (txtbox != null) {
    // Found textbox do something with it
}
```

Comment: Or use _SingleOrDefault_ to throw an exception if there are two elements with the same "data-gel-id" attribute (which should never happen I guess)